# iOS: how to add a titleview across all ViewControllers?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I would like to add a small titleLabel across all pages in my app. titleLabel looks like a tableview section header (as shown in the image)

NB: I want this for viewcontrollers other than UITableViewController too

[image]

How to do this in a reusable way ? Thanks for any advise or reference links to read up on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a `UIView` that has the appearance that you want it to? Then just add that view as a subview whenever you need it.

```
//where "Title" is the view you created

UIView *title = [[Title alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 30,  
                                 self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                 self.view.frame.size.height))];
[self.view addSubview:title];
```